# set OnClickListener for selected item

Tags: android, listview, android-json

I have some data collected from mysql database into a listview (This is a ringtone app).. now i need to set onClickListener on play imageButon for selected item ..
I do know how to set onClickListener, but in this case i dont know how to set it for selected item ..  [image: this is a view of my app]

And this is what i have done so far :

```
public class ListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse
,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private boolean paused = true;

URL url;
Bitmap bmImg = null;



public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

final String LOG = "ListActivity";

private ArrayList<Product> productList;
private ListView lvProduct;
private FunDapter<Product> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.d_activity_list_d);


    ImageLoader.getInstance().init(UILConfig.config(ListActivity.this));

    PostResponseAsyncTask taskRead = new PostResponseAsyncTask(ListActivity.this, this);

     taskRead.execute("http://symphonyrecords.6te.net/product.php");
    lvProduct = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvProduct);
    registerForContextMenu(lvProduct);


}//onCreate


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    final Product selectedProduct = adapter.getItem(info.position);
    Log.d(LOG, selectedProduct.name);

    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.menuUpdate){
        Intent in = new Intent(ListActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        in.putExtra("product", selectedProduct);
        startActivity(in);
    }


    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void  processFinish(String s) {
    productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);

    BindDictionary<Product> dict = new BindDictionary<Product>();
    dict.addStringField(R.id.tvName, new StringExtractor<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String getStringValue(Product product, int position) {
            return product.name;
        }
    });




    adapter = new FunDapter<>(
            ListActivity.this, productList, R.layout.d_layout_list_d, dict);


    lvProduct.setAdapter(adapter);
    lvProduct.setOnItemClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Product selectedProduct = productList.get(position);

}




public void playAndPause(View view1){

            ImageButton button = (ImageButton ) findViewById(R.id.playPause);
    int icon;

    if (paused) {
        paused = false;
        icon = R.drawable.ic_pause;
        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else {
        paused = true;
        icon = R.drawable.ic_play;
        Toast.makeText(ListActivity.this, "Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    button.setImageDrawable(
        ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), icon));

  }



}
```

Comment: Post the code of adapter class

Comment: I used external library (FunDapter) ..

Comment: Then you cant do. why you need to use other adapter just to display view? Make your own adapter if you can. Or May be that adapter has some callback that gives you view reference

Comment: i need this library for many reasons .. but your answer was helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the getView method like this

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // Inflate a new view or use a recycled view.
        View v = convertView;
        GenericViewHolder holder;
        if (null == v) {
            LayoutInflater vi =
                    (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(mLayoutResource, null);
            holder = new GenericViewHolder();
            holder.root = v;
             // There must be view name of that play button
            holder.playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  public void onClick(View v)
       //do your task over here
        }

            // init the sub views and put them in a holder instance
            FunDapterUtils.initViews(v, holder, mBindDictionary);

            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (GenericViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }
}
```